# Events missed while using Watch Service in Java NIO

Tags: java, nio

I was reading up on Java NIO, specifically on **WatchService**. And I found this snippet of code:

```
WatchKey key;
while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
    for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
        //process
    }
    key.reset();
}
```

Now, as we know, take API is a blocking call, which returns null or the **WatchKey** when any registered **StandardWatchEventKinds** occurs. And once we get the key back, it is not queued back again to watch for events until we call the reset API.

Now going back to the code snippet, if we have an event, the key will be returned and we will enter the for loop. Now if the processing logic is time consuming, since the key is already returned we are not watching for any new events. Only when we exit the for loop and call the reset API we start watching again. This could result in some missed events.

Is my assessment correct, or am I missing something here?

Comment: No. It is the watch service that is doing the watching. All you’re doing is reading a queue.

Comment: Okay, so if watch service is doing the watching, then is the watch key acting like the pointer, Marking from which index we need to read the events?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)?